# Tableau Location Filter to Zoom in Map

Tags: filter, geolocation, tableau-api, zooming

Where can I find information on how to use Tableau Location Filter to zoom into a Map.

I have workbook on [Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings/LocalBusinessRatings)

All businesses are in Brooklyn, except one, which is in Boston. How to make the filter selection zoom into a particular location, i.e. `Boston Tea Party` makes the map zoom into Boston, and if I pick other businesses, they zoom back into Brooklyn.

And how to handle if multiple businesses are selected? Perhaps zoom to the middle of the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

On map, click on pin on upper left.

Pin should be "lying down"

[image]

When you select location from drop-down, it zooms in accordingly.

See [public tableau workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings/LocalBusinessRatings)